# Can I remove linux-generic-lts-vivid?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

Can I remove the following packages from my Ubuntu Server?

```
linux-image-generic-lts-vivid
linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid
linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

I'm not being able to install or apdate any package because these three are having configurations problem. Running `dpkg --configure -a` couldn't do the job. So I wondered... Can I remove these three? I do not intend to update my kernel, so if this would be a problem, well... it's not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparently I can.

I decided to try and remove the package off the cuff.

Thanks, guys!

Comment: With a simple apt-get remove

Answer (score 1):

Install the very helpful [byobu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/byobu) package and run

```
sudo purge-old-kernels
```

which may be the safest way to remove what can be removed without endangering your running system.

It may be that your version of Ubuntu has `purge-old-kernel` in the [bikeshed](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/bikeshed) package.

Comment: I'm not being able to install anything because of these dependencies, and I don't have this package.

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the files from the /boot directory manually?

Comment: What can I remove from there? This is what there is in there: 
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/750/400/full/erro.jpg

Comment: a) Decide which kernel version you want to boot
b) Delete the others

PS: Please don't post links to images. They're probably unreadble on smart phones and small screens.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't know it's not recommended to post images.